# Reorder multidimensional arrays manually by array key name

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional PHP array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'apples',
    'name' => 'Apples',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'pears',
    'name' => 'Pears',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'avocados',
    'name' => 'Avocados',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'bananas',
    'name' => 'Bananas',
  ),
)
```

What I'm trying to manually reorder the arrays inside the multidimensional array and list them in exact the following order:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'bananas',
    'name' => 'Bananas',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'avocados',
    'name' => 'Avocados',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'pears',
    'name' => 'Pears',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name_lower' => 'apples',
    'name' => 'Apples',
  ),
)
```

It does not follow a pattern to automatically sort the arrays. It needs to be rearranged manually by name. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @JayBlanchard I've added the working code, including the initial array in a comment for AbraCadaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you index the array on something unique and set an array with the sort order with those unique values, then you can map the sort order array and extract from the main array:

```
$sort = array('bananas', 'avocados', 'pears', 'apples');

$array = array_column($array, null, 'name_lower');
$array = array_map(function($v) use($array) { return $array[$v]; }, $sort);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AbraCadaver! This actually worked perfectly. Here is the working code made using your help: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47f94e676e841c3aa8d2ae923b7fbd5a1416e3e6